# How do I host a WebApplication and a BackgroundService in the same application?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have a command-line application (similar to what would be created with the `dotnet new worker` command) that hosts a `BackgroundService` implementation, like this:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyType>(myinstance);
        // and so on...
    }).Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Now, I would like this application to also host a web api. Currently, I have a whole separate builder that I'm instantiating inside the `MyBackgroundService` class, with a separate set of services/singletons/whatever:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

// ... various web stuff...

var webApi = builder.Build();

// ... more web api stuff...

await webApi.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I'd like to set this up to share a single DI container... how do I do that? My web api uses a `WebApplicationBuilder`, while my `BackgroundService` uses a `DefaultBuilder` (which is a `IHostBuilder`). Is there any way to set this up elegantly?

Edit: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0 which gives me the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` method for the generic host, but the example isn't complete. I can put the `AddControllers()` and `AddRouting()` etc on the generic host, but once I call `Build()` I can't do things like `UseHttpLogging()` or `UseSwagger()` or `MapControllers()`.

Comment: The separate builder is a will or a spite?

Comment: A will or a spite? I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't *want* two builders, but all the web api stuff works with a `WebApplicationBuilder` and not an `IHostBuilder` so I don't know how to not have two builders...

Comment: What is the web framework used?

Comment: Just the normal ASP.NET web api stuff.

Comment: i would suggest to create webapi first and then you can add `services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();` for background service. this way you don't need to deal with all the webapi stuff by yourself. for more details you can refere to this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/running-automatic-task-in-asp-net-core-webapi-d5605b3a1114) which does both.

Comment: @Mark, ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @vernou ASP.NET 6, yes.

Comment: I never tested, but ASP.NET Core can host a background service. Ms Doc : [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're starting from a console app and want to add in the API portion, you can do something like:

```cs
await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<SomeBackgroundService>();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
                services.AddSwaggerGen();
            })
            .Configure((hostContext, app) =>
            {
                if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseSwagger();
                    app.UseSwaggerUI();
                }
​
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            });
        
           //can optionally use a startup file similar to what older versions of .NET used
        //webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();
}
```

Also, assuming you started from a console app, you may need to add:

```cs
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your csproj, as that will pull in the additional web options.

Edit: It appears the services specific to the web context need to be registered within the webBuilder.